# SSO to Grafana embeded in iframe

Tags: authentication, iframe, single-sign-on, grafana

all I have a project that will host Grafana app (whole app not only dashboard/snapshots) inside my website inside an iframe, I'm trying to set a SSO so my users wouldn't have to login to my site then into their Grafana account inside my website.

Grafana version and OS:

- Grafana 10.4.1 enterprise on windows 10

I followed these instructions:

- https://community.grafana.com/t/automatic-login-to-grafana-from-web-application/16801
- https://community.grafana.com/t/grafana-auto-login-from-angular-button-click/71813

I expected to have Grafana auto login the user and open their home route/dashboards

that's my custom.ini file:

```
\[server\]

protocol = http

http_addr = 127.0.0.1

http_port = 8080

domain = 127.0.0.1

enforce_domain = false

\[security\]

allow_embedding = true

\[auth\]

login_cookie_name = grafana_session

disable_login = false

login_maximum_inactive_lifetime_duration =

login_maximum_lifetime_duration =

token_rotation_interval_minutes = 10

disable_login_form = false

api_key_max_seconds_to_live = -1

\[auth.anonymous\]

enabled = true

org_name = Main Org.

org_role = Viewer

\[auth.basic\]

enabled = false

\[auth.proxy\]

enabled = true

header_name = X-WEBAUTH-USER

header_property = username

auto_sign_up = true

sync_ttl = 60

whitelist =

headers =

enable_login_token = false
```

Comment: I don't see any SSO. https://github.com/jangaraj/grafana-iframe?tab=readme-ov-file#i-want-to-have-grafana-in-my-app-as-an-iframe-and-i-would-like-to-have-seamless-login-experience